# asp.net routing in webform - how get route data

Tags: c#, asp.net, routes, webforms

i put this in Global.asax.cs

```
routes.MapWebFormRoute("Page", "Page/{*anything}", "~/Page.aspx", false);
```

how i can get value of {*anything} in Page.aspx

i'm using WebFormRouting from codeplex

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For WebFormRouting, you should check out this blog post by Phil Haack:

**Using Routing With WebForms**
http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/11/using-routing-with-webforms.aspx

He says that, if your Web Form `Page` implements the `IRouteable` interface, the `WebFromRouteHandler` class can pass it the `RequestContext`.  Once this is done, you should be able to:

```
string value = Page.RouteData.Values["anything"];
```

There is a sample project at the blog post.

Comment: i'm using webform, not mvc, i need to get this value in Page_Load of Page.aspx

Comment: In MVC I needed to use `Page.RouteData.Values["anything"]`.